# jQuery if/else with :not isn't working

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ySLkQ/16/

jQuery

```
if ($("h1.change:contains('-')")) {
    $("h1.change").append(" it's negative");
} else if ($("h1.change:not(contains('-'))")) {
    $("h1.change").append(" it's positive");
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class="change">-30</h1>
<h1 class="change">30</h1>
```

Basically no matter what I do, the last `<h1>` always shows negative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `if` is only executed ONCE.

it checks, whether $("h1.change:contains('-')") evaluates to true - it returns one element, so it is true.

afterwards, it applies "it's negative" to all h1.change elements.

The else part is never executed.

```
$("h1.change").not(":contains('-')").append(" it's positive");
$("h1.change:contains('-')").append(" it's negative");
```

will work as you expect - each selector will evaluate to a list of elements, and append() will executed on all elements.

Answer (score 2):

Arun pointed out the missing `:`, but [you can use jQuery to do this a little more efficiently](http://jsfiddle.net/ySLkQ/19/):

```
var change = $("h1.change"),
    negative = change.filter(":contains('-')"),
    positive = change.not(negative);

// you can do the appends above, but I prefer the clarity
negative.append(" it's negative");
positive.append(" it's positive");
```

Also, the first if is always going to effect the other `change` elements. Using the above approach will keep two exclusive groups.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$('h1.change').html(function(val, html){
    return html + ( html.indexOf('-') == -1 ? " it's positive" : " it's negative" )
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/np7Q7/2/)

Comment: If he wants to apply positive and negative to different h1 elements on the page, the code as he suggested won't work - it will append negative/positive to all elements.

Comment: Oops, thanks. It still doesn't work though so I'm guessing another thing might be broken here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through `$.each()` function also. This is better because you want append string to multiple `h1` element with same selector condition. If you try to write single statement, it may cause some problem such as writing same value to multiple elements when not required. Although `$.each()` may not be efficient enough. The answer by @DThought is much better for efficiency sake which you already accepted as answer.

```
$("h1.change").each(function(index){
    if ($(this).text().indexOf("-")!=-1) {
        $(this).append(" it's negative");
    }else{
        $(this).append(" it's positive");
    }
});
```